# Where to find the list of defined CMake properties for Boost?

Tags: boost, cmake

This line of code used to work:

```
get_property(_loc TARGET Boost::Boost PROPERTY LOCATION)
```

But I updated Boost and now I get the following message:

```
get_property could not find TARGET Boost::Boost.  Perhaps it has not yet been created.
```

So I guess that the target `Boost::Boost` does not exist anymore, or that it does not define the `LOCATION` property. I would like to check what properties `find_package(Boost REQUIRED CONFIG COMPONENTS unit_test_framework )` defines when called, but I can't find the information. Is there somewhere in the Boost documentation a list of the CMake properties/targets name?

**Cmake version:** 3.18.1

**Boost version:** 1.71.0

**System:** Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Which version of CMake are you using? The recent version of CMake has built-in support for Boost, see this:https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html

Comment: Ty :)  edited the post to add the version. I had already checked this documentation, but I could not find anything related to `PROPERTY LOCATION` : I don't know where/when this property is defined, I don't know where the target Boost::Boost is defined, and I don't know why it stopped working when I updated Boost :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boost imported targets in CMake are *case-sensitive*. Note, in the CMake 3.14 [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindBoost.html), the Boost target for header-only dependencies is `Boost::boost`.

Furthermore, with CMake versions of 3.15 and above (and newer versions of Boost), the `Boost::boost` imported target has been superseded by [`Boost::headers`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/module/FindBoost.html). It looks like you should be using this `Boost::headers` imported target instead.

You can query the properties for *any* of the Boost imported targets listed in the CMake documentation, such as `Boost::unit_test_framework`. The linked CMake documentation refers to these individual Boost components using `Boost::<C>`, where `<C>` is one of the components.

Comment: Both targets `Boost::boost` and `Boost::headers` give this error:   `INTERFACE_LIBRARY targets may only have whitelisted properties. The   property "LOCATION" is not allowed.`
The CMake documentation does not return any result for a Boost::unit_test_framework query ?

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler That is because these imported targets represent *headers*, not a specific library. As such, the "location" of the targets is more ambiguous. The `LOCATION` property will likely only be defined for imported targets that actually encompass a library file.

Comment: Ok, I get it now :) But why was it working before I uninstalled/reinstalled boost ? Did I break the cmake code by reinstalling only header-only boost libs ?

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler See my updated response for a better explanation. It's hard to say why it worked before, without knowing the versions of everything you used before, and without seeing a minimal, complete example of the CMake code you were using.

Comment: Yes, I really struggle keeping track of the functional states of my code/system and ensuring repeatability :'( I'll mark this question as answered, since you actually answered most of the points :)